# When generator is used in for loop, only one item is yielded

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

I am having problems with python generators when used in a for loop. In my example code I have a generator that will yield two items. However, the for loop will only iterate on the first one.

I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong here, or if Python is not behaving as expected.

The python version I am running is:
`Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

```py
class Event:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def ready(self):
        return True

class EventRunner:
    def __init__(self):
        self.events = []

    def create_event(self, name):
        self.events.append(Event(name))

    def run(self):
        ready_events = (e for e in self.events if e.ready())
        dbg_ready_events = (e for e in self.events if e.ready())
        print("dbg: these are the events that are ready", list(dbg_ready_events))
        for event in ready_events:
            print("event \"{}\" is ready".format(event.name))
            self.events.remove(event)

event_runner = EventRunner()
event_runner.create_event("1")
event_runner.create_event("2")

event_runner.run()
```

The expected output would be:

```
event "1" is ready
event "2" is ready
```

However, when executing it, it only outputs:

```
event "1" is ready
```

I added a debug line to show that the generator can yield the two items:

`dbg: these are the events that are ready [<__main__.Event object at 0x0388A460>, <__main__.Event object at 0x0388A448>]`

Comment: Because you `.remove` from your list while you iterate over it. Don't do that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are right! Thank you